# highmaps usa county map not coloring counties for Nebraska, New Mexico, or New York

Tags: json, highcharts, highmaps

I'm getting close to finishing a side project using the awesome HighMaps. As a test, I sent data to all 3142 counties which should have colored them all in green. Strangely, the states of Nebraska, New Mexico, and New York are not colored. My data seems to be complete, with an example of data sent for Nebraska shown below:

NB\",\"value\":2}" },
            { 31003, "{\"code\":\"us-nb-003\",\"name\":\"Antelope County, NB\",\"value\":2}" },
            { 31005, "{\"code\":\"us-nb-005\",\"name\":\"Arthur County, NB\",\"value\":2}" },
            { 31007, "{\"code\":\"us-nb-007\",\"name\":\"Banner County, NB\",\"value\":2}" },
            { 31009, "{\"code\":\"us-nb-009\",\"name\":\"Blaine County, NB\",\"value\":2}" },

Any ideas that might turn the light on for me? I'm so close to getting my desired result after many months of work - I'm exited to figure out this issue.

Comment: Please provide a complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: a example which you have tried would be helping us better analyse the problem. Can you please add some jsfiddle you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

**Embarrassed** - the data I imported (which I created) had an error for the three states listed. Now the map is displaying all counties as selected. I should have been a better detective instead of thinking there might be a limitation in the map. The specific import issue had the wrong state codes inserted into the data for the three states that were failing.

What I had that was failing:
{ 31003, "{\"code\":\"us-nb-003\",\"name\":\"Antelope County, NB\",\"value\":2}" },

What it should have been:
{ 31003, "{\"code\":\"us-ne-003\",\"name\":\"Antelope County, NE\",\"value\":2}" },

Also, the state code for Nebraska is NE, not NB
Sorry for wasting your time!